# How any attack on a cipher carried out? Are these practical or only theoretical?

Tags: encryption, provable-security, attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I have been reading about successful attacks on AES and other ciphers. One such mention is [here (see excerpt below)](https://cr.yp.to/streamciphers/why.html):

> AES was published under the name Rijndael in 1998. Refereed
>   cryptanalytic papers in the next three years culminated in attacks
>   taking time "only" $2^{140}$ to break 7 rounds of 256-bit AES and "only"
>   $2^{204}$ (with a huge amount of memory) to break 8 rounds of 256-bit AES.
>   Subsequent work made very little progress. (Related-key attacks can
>   break more rounds but are not of concern in any properly designed
>   cryptographic protocol.)

I want to know:

1. If any paper mentions attack as $2^{140}$, how the researchers determine this number of operations?
2. Are these attacks only on paper or practically proven?
3. Considering super-computers owned by the government, which researchers don't have access, this figure may vary? Are these attacks taking into account super-computers computing power also?

Comment: When DJB mentions _attacks taking time "only" $2^{140}$ to break 7 rounds of 256-bit AES_, I believe he refers to Henri Gilbert & Marine Minier's [_A Collision Attack on 7 Rounds of Rijndael_](http://perso.citi.insa-lyon.fr/mminier/papers/GilbertMinier_AES00.pdf), in proceedings of AES Candidate Conference , pp. 230-241, 2000.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for that update. I cited the above attack only as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in order:

**1. If any paper mentions attack as $2^{140}$, how the researchers determine this number of operations?**

By examining the mathematical properties of the algorithm and their attack.

**2. Are these attacks only on paper or practically proven?**

There is no practical way to perform *any* operation $2^{140}$ times, so they are only on paper. But note that mathematics is one of the few sciences where we can prove things *without* resorting to experimentation.

**3. Considering super-computers owned by the government, which researchers don't have access, this time-frame may vary? Are these attacks taking into account super-computers computing power also?**

$2^{140}$ is the number of elementary operations, usually 1 operation takes a constant amount of operations of the underlying primitive, e.g. 1 AES encryption/decryption operation. The number of operations required does not depend on computer speed.

But yes, faster computers will perform the operations faster. This is however of little importance as $2^{140}$ operations together take multiple universes of time and energy to complete. Only very disruptive technology such as quantum computing or breakthroughs in mathematics *could* make such attacks practical.

There is always the possibility that the attack itself can be improved upon. Attacks get better, never worse.

---

The results on 256 bit AES with relayed keys are mainly of importance when the block cipher is used within other constructions such as pseudo random number generators. AES encryption is still considered secure.

Comment: Edited OP. Changed time-frame to operations.

Comment: Added " The number of operations required does not depend on computer speed." to the answer as reaction on the edit.

Comment: After reading this I am a bit worried on any claim that AES is secure: https://www.propublica.org/article/standards-agency-strongly-suggests-dropping-its-own-encryption-standard

Comment: @RPK There is definitely a difference. AES was chosen as winner of a crypto competition. It was designed by Belgian cryptographers. Dual DRBG was pushed to be a standard and seemed to offer little to no advantage over existing primitives based on symmetric ciphers (based on either a hash or block cipher such as AES).

Comment: After Snowden incident, I feel cascaded encryption like TrueCrypt is the right choice. And probably this is one of the reason why TrueCrypt is not available now.

Comment: Why? The Snowden documents show a lot of clandestine operations by the security services of the USA. But it doesn't seem to show any unknown cryptographic analyses of standardized ciphers - at least to my knowledge. I'm pretty sure Bruce would have something to say on that if that was the case.

Comment: In addition to the answers, it is important to stress that even if 7-round AES would be considered insecure (and $2^{140}$ isn't), on its own that would not matter. AES 256 has 14 rounds. Attacks on reduced round versions are not attacks on the system itself, they are more indicators to what kind of attack might work.